# Bluetooth printer compatible with android

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have to Develop an  billing application for android devices.On the application there must be a provision for print the invoices using any bluetooth/Wifi printer.But upon my knowledge android doesnot support printing via Printer.is there any way or any tutorial upon it?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to print it using a standard printer driver,you just need to write bytes to a Bluetooth enabled printer,for testing our Bluetooth apps we usually make use of a printer which has a Bluetooth facility. You need to refer Bluetooth `server socket` [image]http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothSocket.html